# Cookie not being saved

Tags: session, cookies

I am currently working on my API which is in charge of authentication and all the API endpoints being consumed on my SPA. The API is running on `api.domain.com` and the SPA is running on `www.domain.com`. All on the same SSL certificate (wildcard type).

Unfortunately when i return `Set-cookie` in the header from `api.domain.com` it is not saved, but i can see it in Chromes debugger.

My session is as following:

`'Set-cookie':'__Secure-ID=38afes7a8-38afes7a8-38afes7a8-38afes7a8; Expires=Mon, 11-Sep-2017 23:03:13 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly; Domain=.domain.com'`

Theres no problems retrieving it and reviewing it in the browser, but it won't stay and does not obey the Expire, it simply disappears when i navigate into other endpoints of `api.domain.com` or even `www.domain.com`.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Your `Expires` field isn't using the [proper format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Date). You should change the `Expires` field to `Mon, 11 Sep 2017 23:03:13 GMT`.